# useContext is returning undefined when attempting to access nested objects

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using hooks to get access to data and if I console.log the first level of data, I get everything including the objects nested in the initial object. If I try to access any of the data, it is returned undefined.

Component accessing data

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';

import { GlobalContext } from '../contexts/GlobalState';

export default function BlogDetail(props) {
    const { blogPostToEdit, getBlogWithId } = useContext(GlobalContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        getBlogWithId(props.match.params.id)
    }, [])

    const { title, content, tags, date, userId } = blogPostToEdit;
    const parsedDate = new Date(date);
    console.log(blogPostToEdit)
    console.log(userId);
    return (
        <div className='blog-detail-wrapper'>
            <div className='blog-title'>
                {title}
            </div>
            <div className='blog-detail-date'>
                <div>{parsedDate.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + parsedDate.getDate() + '/' + parsedDate.getFullYear()}</div>
            </div>
            <div className='blog-content'>
                {content}
            </div>
            <div className='blog-tags'>
                {tags}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

Context

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import BlogReducer from '../reducers/BlogReducer';

const initialState = {
  blogPosts: [],
  blogPostToEdit: {},
  error: null
}

export const GlobalContext = createContext(initialState);

export const GlobalProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(BlogReducer, initialState);

  async function getBlogPosts() {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/blogPost/getPosts');

      dispatch({
        type: 'GET_BLOGS',
        payload: res.data
      })
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_ERROR',
        payload: err.resposonse.data.error
      })
    }
  }

  async function getBlogWithId(id) {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/blogPost/getPostById/${id}`);

      dispatch({
        type: 'GET_BLOG_ID',
        payload: res.data
      })
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_ERROR',
        payload: err.resposonse.data.error
      })
    }
  }

  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider value={{
      blogPosts: state.blogPosts,
      blogPostToEdit: state.blogPostToEdit,
      auth: state.auth,
      error: state.error,
      getBlogPosts,
      getBlogWithId
    }}>
      {children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Reducer

```
export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_BLOGS':
      return {
        ...state,
        blogPosts: action.payload
      }
    case 'GET_BLOG_ID':
      return {
        ...state,
        blogPostToEdit: action.payload
      }
    default: return state;
  }
}
```

This is what the data looks like

```
blogPostToEdit:{
content: "Right now I'm all stressing it out because I can't seem to know how to work with state and..."
date: "2020-01-02T01:18:04.488Z"
tags: ["RouterLink, Javascript, react, dummydumtime"]
title: "This is whole new blog for a whole new year"
userId:{
    date: "2019-08-27T23:27:42.945Z"
    email: "gloob@email.com"
    name: "gloob"
    password: "***"
    _id: "5d65bc6e4402213647f8704b"
}
_id: "5e0d44cc5ba6ddb32418c760"
}
```

What I'm trying to do is get access to the name and but it's returned undefined when I try to use it. This could be a repeated question but I can't seem to find the answer. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you can get blogPostToEdit but userId is undefined? If so, could you post an example of blogPostToEdit?

Comment: userId is defined if I console.log(blogPostsToEdit) and the data inside of userId is returned if I console.log that too. It's when I try to console.log anything inside of userId that it comes back undefined. For example, if I run console.log(userId.name) then it's returned undefined. I added an example to the post so you can see what the data looks like

Comment: In the first render of BlogDetail component, coz the init value of userId is not set in context. Then it is initialized in the second render after calling getBlogWithId. So you need to check if userId is null or not, using userId && userId.name, or set value for userId in initialState.

Comment: So I set a value for userId in initialState, but just out of curiosity, what would the conditional look like if I was checking if those two variables were null?